# Test data endpoints

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Here I want to test the data output on the endpoint.

My test:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import axios from "axios";
import CompBuildingGeo from "./components/CompBuildingGeo";
import { getBuildingGEO } from "../../service/building";

const buildingGeo = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await getBuildingGEO();
    console.log(result?.map((total) => total.total_building));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("salah");
  } finally {
    console.log("none");
  }
};

describe("Component Building", () => {

  test("CompBuildingGeo API", async () => {
    render(<CompBuildingGeo />);
    jest.spyOn(axios, "get").mockReturnValue({
      data: [
        {
          total_building: "76915222",
        },
      ],
    });
    const result = await buildingGeo();
    expect(result).toBe("76915222");
  });
});
```

However, when I `npm run test`, this error appears:

```
Expected: "76915222"
Received: undefined

  35    |      });
  36    |    const result = await buildingGeo();
> 37    |   expect(result?.map((total) => total.total_buildings)).toBe("76915222");
        |   
  38    |  });
  39    |});
```

What is the cause of the error?

Comment: You forgot to return from `buildingGeo`

Comment: how to return buildingGeo, sir ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add a `return` statement to `buildingGeo` function, so instead of:

```
  try {
    const result = await getBuildingGEO();
    console.log(result?.map((total) => total.total_building));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("salah");
  } finally {
    console.log("none");
  }
};
```

It will be:

```
const buildingGeo = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await getBuildingGEO();
    console.log(result?.map((total) => total.total_building));
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("salah");
  } finally {
    console.log("none");
  }
};
```

I'm not 100% percent sure, but you might have to access the `data` property before returning (`result.data`), but the code above should work.

The `undefined` you were getting was happening because your function was not returning anything.

Comment: still getting undefined in received

Comment: Can you share your current code again, please?

Comment: Also, what does the return of your endpoint looks like?

Answer (score -2):

I edited this part =>

```
const buildingGeo = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.get(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_DISTRICT}/buildingCountGeoSettleAll`,
      {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      }
    );
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("salah");
  } finally {
    console.log("none");
  }
};
```

and work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).